# How to populate HTML Combo box with JSON object

Tags: javascript

I am creating an user registration form using jsp,in which there is an option to select State from a combo box.I am using a simple html combo box but i am receiving State as a json object from web service.So how to populate the combo box with json object.

State Json is as follows,

```
{"States":[{"id":"1","stateName":"Alabama","code":"AL"},
{"id":"4","stateName":"Arkansas","code":"AR"},
{"id":"8","stateName":"Delaware","code":"DE"}]}
```

My Javascript function is,

```
function getStates(){    
url = WSPath;
response=initiateRequest(url);}
```

My HTML combo box is `<select name="State">`

I need to populate the combo-box with the above json object.

Comment: A combobox is a combination of a drop down menu and a text input (hence the name). A select element won't generate one.

Comment: Don't do this with JavaScript, it's inefficient and less reliable than plain (on the client) HTML. Do it with JSP, and cache the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure js:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
var obj = JSON.parse(response);

for (var i=0; i < obj.States.length; i++)
{
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.id = obj.States[i].id;
  option.value = obj.States[i].code;
  option.innerHTML = obj.States[i].stateName;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Tweak the id, value and innerHTML to your needs.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.I did tried as you mentioned but i received an error at var obj = JSON.parse(response);

Comment: What is the error? I don't know how you're reading the json. I was assuming that response contains the json string. If it's already parsed then you don't need that call to JSON.parse.

Comment: "states" is useless you need the array with objects inside.

Comment: @B.F. I don't get your point, `obj.States` is an array of objects

Comment: @mihai Your code is ok! I wonder why there is the "States" key with one array item in the JSON.